# Why is std::forward turning my lvalue into an rvalue?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
template<class T>
struct IntHolder {
    T i;
};

template<class T>
void addOne(T& t) {
    t.i += 1;
}

template<class... Args>
void addAll(Args... args) {
      // Magic to run addOne on each arg
      int dummy[] = { 0, ((void)addOne(std::forward<Args>(args)), 0)... };
}

int main() {
    IntHolder<int> x{2};
    IntHolder<double> t{3};
    addAll(x, t);
    return 0;
}
```

This toy example won't compile because

```
prog.cc: In instantiation of 'void addAll(Args ...) [with Args = {IntHolder<int>, IntHolder<double>}]':
prog.cc:60:16:   required from here
prog.cc:54:39: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'IntHolder<int>&' from an rvalue of type 'IntHolder<int>'
       int dummy[] = { 0, ((void)addOne(std::forward<Args>(args)), 0)... };
                                       ^
prog.cc:48:6: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'void addOne(T&) [with T = IntHolder<int>]'
 void addOne(T& t) {
```

What I thought would happen here is that addAll gets two lvalues passed in, and then addOne would be called on each of those as an lvalue. However, it seems somewhere along the way, the compiler thinks that the argument is getting converted to an rvalue. Why might this be?

Comment: `void addAll(Args... args)` needs to be `void addAll(Args&&... args)` for it to be a proper forwarding, as is, your call to forward is equivalent to `std::move()`

Comment: As `addOne` expect lvalue reference, I would go `template<class... Args>
void addAll(Args&... args)` and get rid of `std::forward`.

Answer (score 6):

You're declaring parameter as non-reference, i.e. pass-by-value, then when being passed `x` and `t`, the type would be deduced as `IntHolder<int>` and `IntHolder<double>`. Then `std::forward<Args>` would convert them into rvalues.

For [forwarding reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references) it should be

```
template<class... Args>
void addAll(Args&&... args) {
    //          ^^
    // Args would be deduced as IntHolder<int>&, IntHolder<double>&
    // then std::forward<Args>(args) yields lvalues 
    int dummy[] = { 0, ((void)addOne(std::forward<Args>(args)), 0)... };
}
```